# Coloring png files in IE11

Tags: icons, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, citrix

I am looking for a way to color png icons in css. I need compatibility with Citrix in IE11 mode Edge, and .svg files are blocked by citrix. Therefore, I need to use .png icons. However, I cannot use css filters to recolor the icons in IE11 - therefore I need another solution.

Comment: If possible, could you provide a simple code that we can reproduce this issue? Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Essentially any <img> tag using a .svg file will be blocked by citrix.